# Loop For to compare the content between two cells and copy data

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA code to compare the content (string) between two cells. If it is the same, I must to copy certain cells and paste them in another sheet. However, this code is not working. Please may you advise on how to adjust it?

```
Dim p As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For i = 12 To RealLastRow
If Worksheets("Pal_clave").Range("V" & i).Value = Worksheets("Pal_clave").Range("V" & i - 1).Value Then

Worksheets("Pal_clave").Range("D" & i).Copy Worksheets("Diagrama").Range("B" & p + 10)

Worksheets("Pal_clave").Range("K" & i).Copy Worksheets("Diagrama").Range("E" & p + 10)

Worksheets("Pal_clave").Range("T" & i).Copy Worksheets("Diagrama").Range("H" & p + 10)

Worksheets("Pal_clave").Range("V" & i).Copy Worksheets("Diagrama").Range("K" & p + 10)

Worksheets("Pal_clave").Range("AB" & i).Copy Worksheets("Diagrama").Range("N" & p + 10)

Worksheets("Pal_clave").Range("AJ" & i).Copy Worksheets("Diagrama").Range("B" & p + 20)

Worksheets("Pal_clave").Range("Y" & i).Copy Worksheets("Diagrama").Range("K" & p + 20)

p = p + 20

End If

Next i
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Are you getting an error on a specific line or is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: `RealLastRow` - what is that? Is it a function? If so, is the Function present and reachable by the module?

Comment: @DarrellH Exactly... the code is not doing what I expect.

Comment: @CLR RealLasRow is used to identify the last row of the sheet "Pal_clave", like this: RealLastRow = Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

Answer (score 1):

It may be that some of your Subroutine is missing, but you do not define `RealLastRow`.  You can shorten your code by setting your long worksheet names as variables and avoiding copy/paste.  It is best not to use `Select` and `Activate` as used in the previous answer.

```
Sub LoopFor()

    'Use Long in case there are greater than 32767 rows
    Dim p As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim RealLastRow As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    'Makes your code shorter
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pal_clave")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Diagrama")

    'This will get you the last row, even if there are gaps in the data
    RealLastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'You may want to test if there are more than 12 rows
    For i = 12 To RealLastRow
        If ws1.Range("V" & i).Value = ws1.Range("V" & i - 1).Value Then

            'No need to copy/paste
            ws2.Range("B" & p + 10) = ws1.Range("D" & i)
            ws2.Range("E" & p + 10) = ws1.Range("K" & i)
            ws2.Range("H" & p + 10) = ws1.Range("T" & i)
            ws2.Range("K" & p + 10) = ws1.Range("V" & i)
            ws2.Range("N" & p + 10) = ws1.Range("AB" & i)
            ws2.Range("B" & p + 20) = ws1.Range("AJ" & i)
            ws2.Range("K" & p + 20) = ws1.Range("Y" & i)

            p = p + 20

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you have input [sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53iL8.png) like this and you want compare the cells in A and B columns. If the string matches, copy the particular cell values from sheet1 and paste them into [sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz0Jc.png).

You have to use a `For` loop and `if` condition to achieve this.

Try this below code.

```
Sub CompareAndCopy()

Dim NumberOfValues, i, j As Integer
Dim value1, value2 As String
j = 2

Sheet1.Activate
NumberOfValues = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 1 To NumberOfValues

value1 = Range("A" & i).Value
value2 = Range("B" & i).Value

'Comparing the cell values in A and B column
'If value matches then copy and paste them into sheet2 from sheet1

If value1 = value2 Then   
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i & ":H" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & j)
Sheet1.Activate
j = j + 1
End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Nandan, fair play for having a go but I think you might have made a few too many assumptions here without more info. Also, normally we would steer OP away from using Select / Activate and as they've written code without it (which looks fine) I wouldn't recommend they start using it.

Comment: @CLR, Is it good to use Set and Range functions to select cells?

Comment: That would be far better. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Thank you, i will improve it :)

Comment: @NandanA Thank you.

Comment: @CarolinaMontoyaPachongo, Does my answer fits your question?

Comment: @NandanA Not really. Unfortunately, the issure is more complex than expected. I had to add another For within the first loop. Thanks anyway!